# Why does the random generator not work? discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const { Client, Attachment, Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

const items = [ "Test1", "Test2", "Test3"

]

const item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];

module.exports = {
    name: "test",
    description: "",

    /**
     * @param {Message} message 
     * @param {Client} client 
     */
    
    execute(message, args, client) {

        const mess = "You win:"

        var embed = new MessageEmbed();
        if (item == "Test1") {
            embed.setDescription(mess + " Test1")
        } else if (item == "Test2") {
            embed.setDescription(mess + " Test2")
        } else if (item == "Test3") {
            embed.setDescription(mess + " Test3")
        }
        embed.setTitle("tEsT")
        embed.setColor('#bd2ecc')

        const embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Searching...")
        .setColor("bd2ecc")

        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed1]}).then((msg) => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                msg.edit({content: "\n", embeds: [embed]})
            }, 3000)
        });

    }
};
```

I'm trying to get the embed to respond to one of the contents of "items", unfortunately nothing is generated randomly, and I'm wondering how to fix this, I have about a guess because only test3 is always displayed, but no idea how to fix it

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Why not do `embed.setDescription(mess + item)`

Comment: what difference does it make? my question was a different one <3

Comment: The if statements are redundant, you check what `item` is, only to send `item`. Remove a step and just send `item`. I commented this because the statements *could* be causing an issue, otherwise we need more debugging details than "nothing is generated randomly"

Comment: `const item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];` should be inside the `execute` method. And @Elitezen's advice is correct.

Comment: It works when it is in execute, I could have thought of that. Thank you both <3